# Desktop desn't loads after reboot

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, plank, desktop

I am using Elementary OS Loki and sometimes when I reboot or turn on the laptop, after login screen, wingpanel and Plank doesn't show up. How can I debug this? where I can find log files or something?

Comment: Had the same issue. It all started by completely losing the Dock first.
Then slowly slowly the whole thing. I ended up reinstalling unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's apparently a known bug, you can try what I explained here [Significant lag loading panel and dock after login (Loki)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/significant-lag-loading-panel-and-dock-after-login-loki)
to temporarily avoid to reboot