# pantheon desktop takes a long time to load

Tags: boot, pantheon

my pantheon desktop takes a long time to load, what's something that wasn't present before. The login screen appears immediately, but after I enter the password and the desktop is loading, it takes like 30-40 seconds which I don't consider normal as I'm running a i5 + 8 GB RAM + SSD computer.

I have also tried to disable all of my start-up scripts.

My installed apps (out of the AppCenter) are:
WPS Office
Viber
Messenger for Desktop
Spotify
Vivaldi, Opera

the rest is from the AppCenter.

Also, it's very incosistent in happening. Sometimes it happens, sometimes it loads immediately. I have tried it even now and it loaded immediately, twice before it had the delay.

Any idea what might be causing this? If any logs are needed, just let me know what to put into terminal and I'll provide them.

//although I'm no developer, I'd say maybe it's because I'm connecting to the internet through WiFi and it's somehow dependant on it?

Thanks!

Comment: oh, so the desktop comes up eventually? :D I usually just hard reset as i thought it got stuck somehow.. but it doesn't happen to me frequently, maybe 1 in 10 boots.. or maybe i have different issue - next time i'll try to wait longer :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate

[Delay to Start Elementary OS 0.4 Loki (64-bit)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10726/delay-to-start-elementary-os-0-4-loki-64-bit/10727#10727)

Try this:

```
mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled
```

Comment: This really helped, thank you :) and sorry, I forgot to look on the past posts for some reason.

Comment: Same story with me. Helped me a lot : )

Comment: But now I am curious: what is at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop and how can it be that it has an internal timeout of minutes?