# Reporting bugs where?

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, plank

I want to ask you where the bugs can be reported?
Most annoying, what I found in the Loki release: after update & restart every time the wingpanel and plank stops loading. I had just an empty screen, as workaround I kill the Xorg from the console.

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Bugs can be reported at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary

This one you mention seems to come up quite a bit.

If you would like to put a bounty on a bug, you can do so here.

https://www.bountysource.com/teams/elementary/issues

If you don't know, a bounty is where you can put money towards a bug to give incentive to get it fixed quicker/give it priority.

Comment: The Launchpad link says that none of the projects use Launchpad for bug tracking.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you aren't affected by this same issue as I was?

[pantheon desktop takes a long time to load](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11330/pantheon-desktop-takes-a-long-time-to-load)

try to rename the file throught terminal:

```
mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled
```