# Elementary OS will not load at

Tags: desktop, elementary-website

[image]

Hey guys. So I load up my laptop this morning and elementary isn't loading anything other than my wallpaper as seen in the photo.

I can't access the dock at all, however I can mouse over ares of the taskbar where say for example the battery status icon and shutdown features are, but I can not access any apps.

I attempted an update through the termial (alt,ctrl,f1) and sat throughout the update process and rebooted. Unfortunately, I still having the same problem of the desktop not loading.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a duplicate of a duplicate. It's related to a known bug.

Since you can't access anything type Ctrl+Alt+T to open the terminal and enter:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled
```

Source: [pantheon desktop takes a long time to load](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11330/pantheon-desktop-takes-a-long-time-to-load/11332#11332)