# Problem in loading the desktop in ELementaryOs!

Tags: desktop

After a big update before multiple days, it is taking more than 1 min to load the desktop even I have an SSD and before that update, it was loading it immediately. How this issue can be solved?

Comment: I can confirm this problem. Mine does not take more than 1min but it sure takes about 10 seconds on a fresh install.
I will try to do some investigation to see what is taking so long

Comment: @FabioPicchi What shall we do? shall we open an issue?

Comment: Execute from terminal `sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain` to see what's delaying the boot so much. Also post the output of `uname -r`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some top panel indicator application which is stacked to load the timeout is exactly 60 sec. So then it failed is release the loading of your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in [Loki](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12733/elementary-os-will-not-load-at/12737#12737). It's an issue related to the at-spi dbus. I have not experienced it in Juno, but what I would recommend is executing the following line:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled
```

I have a long list of "fixes/workaround" that could be applicable for many issues within elementary, affectionately known as eLC or the elementary OS Combobulator. Unfortunately I have not had a chance to test them all in Juno. But they might come in useful for you and others.

https://gist.github.com/PretzelJones/05ff9ae2af0570b86aaebc385c341428