# Wingpanel clock is out of sync with system time

Tags: wingpanel, time, clock

I recently noticed that the time displayed in the wingpanel is roughly one minute behind the system time, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

The system time is NTP synchronized, and my OS is `elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki`. I also checked that the BIOS time (shown with `hwclock --show`) is correct.

Has anyone noticed a similar problem and knows how to synchronize the wingpanel clock with the system time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a known bug in the indicator that caused the time to be up to 1 minute out of sync with the system time, especially when sleeping and resuming the computer.

You can read more information about the issue and how it was fixed here if you're interested:
https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-datetime/pull/17

Code has been pushed to resolve the issue, but that update hasn't been pushed out to users yet. The next time the indicator is updated, the problem will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks again for submitting your fix, it just has been released with version 2.0.2!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, this seems to be related to the slow login problem with Loki, e.g. mentioned in [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10726/delay-to-start-elementary-os-0-4-loki-64-bit).

After applying the same fix as proposed in a [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377/comments/22) of the official [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377), the wingpanel clock is now again in sync with the system time:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop.backup
```

I will update this answer if the problem occurs again.

Comment: While this might improve the symptoms of the problem, it wasn't the cause of the issue. I'll add an answer with more information.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will mark your answer as accepted since it describes the cause of the issue as well as it references your pull request solving the problem.