# Login slow even though booting is fast

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, greeter

I'm on elementaryOS 0.4.1 Loki with an SSD as my boot drive, so I have very fast booting. However, whenever I log in, it takes an agonizing 60 seconds for wingpanel to appear.

Here is my Xorg log. What should I do?

https://hastebin.com/orapodijup.hs

Comment: same here. 2 minutes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is already a bug report for this problem, see [Bug #1596377](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377).

As suggested in the [comments](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377/comments/22), the following workaround seems to fix the problem for some users:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop.backup
```

This worked for me, no delayed startup for the last couple of days (before it was ~2min after every boot).

**Update:**
Probably a duplicate of question [10726](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10726/delay-to-start-elementary-os-0-4-loki-64-bit)

Comment: It seems to somewhat work. Boot times vary from instantaneous (like before) to 10 seconds, which is a lot better than 60. I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: on eOS 5.1 this not working